# Text reappearing after clear in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: terminal, jetbrains-ide

I've found that when using the terminal in JetBrains IDEs if I use `clear` or `cls` in the terminal and then scroll up the "cleared" content is still there. This is irritating as I like to clear the terminal between each run of the compiler so that I don't mix up errors/warnings from one compile with previous compile(s).

Does anyone know how to fix this so when I clear something it's actually gone? Thanks

Comment: Found this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-331625 --> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-283704. **EDIT** Or maybe actually it's  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230112